# multiply condition in actionscript-3 does not work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When i try to make a multiply condition. it's always error. can you tell me where my fault? Thanks

```
var score:Number = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, totalScore);

function totalScore(e:Event){
    if(
        to_konten1_1.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_2.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_3.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_4.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_5.visible = false &&
        score > 20){
            gotoAndStop(2);
    } else if(
        to_konten1_1.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_2.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_3.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_4.visible = false &&
        to_konten1_5.visible = false &&
        score < 20){
            gotoAndStop(3);
        }
```

Comment: Include also the error in your question, otherwise it's hard to guess what's wrong. +Set **Permit debugging** on at **File** -> **Publish settings** to see where the error triggers from.

Comment: Because comparison operator is **==**, not **=**.

Comment: Use more brackets. `if ((something)&&(something)&&(...))`. And also what @Organis said.

Answer (score 2):

I think this worth explaining a bit. The **if (condition)** expression **needs** condition to be **Boolean** but does not require so. Instead, it tries to cast the given expression by the number of rules to get its **Boolean** value.

**Boolean**: A => A.

Assignation operator "**=**": A=B => B.

**null**, **undefined**, **void**: always **false**.

**Number**, **int**, **uint**: 0 => **false**, **Number.NaN** => **false**, otherwise **true**.

**String**: "" => **false**, otherwise **true**.

**Listing**: A,B,C => C, although this expression has no particular meaning in AS3 it always returns its last element.

Any valid **Array**, **Object**, **Function**, **Class** or class instance: always **true**.

Thus, in your case you could formalize it a bit:

```
function totalScore(e:Event):void
{
    if (!anyVisible)
    {
        if (score > 20)
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
        else if (score < 20)
        {
            gotoAndStop(3);
        }
        else // if score == 20
        {
            // Decide what to do.
        }
    }
}

function get anyVisible():Boolean
{
    var aList:Array = [to_konten1_1, to_konten1_2, to_konten1_3, to_konten1_4, to_konten1_5];

    for each (var DO:DisplayObject in aList)
    {
        if (DO.visible)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you are using a single = for assignment instead of using a double == for comparison.